# Spark SQL: automatic schema from csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

does spark sql provide any way to automatically load csv data?
I found the following Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2360 but it was closed....

Currently I would load a csv file as follows:

```
case class Record(id: String, val1: String, val2: String, ....)

 sc.textFile("Data.csv")
.map(_.split(",")) 
.map { r =>                  
   Record(r(0),r(1), .....)
}.registerAsTable("table1")
```

Any hints on the automatic schema deduction from csv files? In particular a) how can I generate a class representing the schema and  b) how can I automatically fill it (i.e. Record(r(0),r(1), .....))?

Update:
I found a partial answer to the schema generation here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#data-sources

```
// The schema is encoded in a string
val schemaString = "name age"
// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val schema =
 StructType(
schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
// Convert records of the RDD (people) to Rows.
val rowRDD = people.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).trim))
// Apply the schema to the RDD.
val peopleSchemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
```

So the only question left would be how to do the step
  `map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).trim))` dynamically for the given number of attributes?

Thanks for your support!
Joerg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) where you can save a few keystrokes not having to define the column names and auto-use the headers.

Comment: I think the original question is asking about working with `case class` instead of `DataFrame`

Comment: @user955091 your reasoning for downvoting is not taking into consideration: 1) the question is more about finding a solution resolving around spark sql and csv than it is about case classes, 2) the answer has been accepted by the question's author, 3) the answer has accumulated 4 upvotes prior to your downvote. So don't you think that your downvoting is a little harsh?

Answer (score 5):

```
val schemaString = "name age".split(" ")
// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val schema =   StructType(schemaString.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
val lines = people.flatMap(x=> x.split("\n"))
val rowRDD = lines.map(line=>{
  Row.fromSeq(line.split(" "))
})
val peopleSchemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
```

May be this link will help you.

http://devslogics.blogspot.in/2014/11/spark-sql-automatic-schema-from-csv.html